# Web app for a docker container started but also timed out

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have a node app running on localhost:3000 and want to deploy it publicly. Doing this by running inside a VM and using port forwarding was easy, but I'm struggling with docker and deployment of a container.

I just pushed a new container image to my private docker repo with `docker-compose push` and have continuous deployment enabled in my Azure web app. The logs show it running the image with `docker run` subcommand within the web app automatically as expected.

It takes a really long time for my app within the container to run, and by the time it runs, it times out and Azure seems to terminate it.

My env vars needed for app to run were manually entered in Application Settings within the Azure portal for the web app.

```
2018_09_18_RD00155D258812_default_docker.log:
2018-09-18T00:14:27.228360304Z   level: 'info',
2018-09-18T00:14:27.228366005Z   label: 'app/server.js',
2018-09-18T00:14:27.228370005Z   timestamp: '2018-09-18T00:14:27.226Z',
2018-09-18T00:14:27.228374605Z   [Symbol(level)]: 'info' }
2018-09-18T00:14:27.844023142Z { message: 'createdQueue; results = {"name":"webhook-queue-dev","approximateMessageCount":1,"created":false}',
2018-09-18T00:14:27.844050643Z   level: 'debug',
2018-09-18T00:14:27.844055943Z   label: 'data-controllers/azure-queue.js',
2018-09-18T00:14:27.844060543Z   timestamp: '2018-09-18T00:14:27.843Z',
2018-09-18T00:14:27.844065044Z   [Symbol(level)]: 'debug' }

2018_09_18_RD00155D258812_docker.log:
2018-09-18 00:14:10.809 INFO  - Starting container for site
2018-09-18 00:14:10.809 INFO  - docker run -d -p 18365:80 --name webhook-web-app_0 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=webhook-web-app -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=123 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 jtara1/webhook  

2018-09-18 00:18:04.705 ERROR - Container webhook-web-app_0 for site webhook-web-app did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.8677441 sec
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  webhook:
    image: jtara1/webhook
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: node server.js
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules/
    expose:
      - "3000"
      - "80"
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

# Expose our server port.
EXPOSE 3000 80

# Run our app.
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

---

I test the same container image on localhost with

```
   $ docker-compose up -d
   $ docker-compose exec webhook sh
   > wget localhost:3000
   $ docker-compose logs
   $ docker-compose down
```

Comment: Why don't you just use Dockerfile to build the image if it just has one service?

Comment: Ok, I'll try pushing an image using `$ docker` instead of `$ docker-compose`. 
`docker build -t webhook2 .`
`docker push jtara1/webhook`

Comment: So do you solve the problem now?

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT no, that didn't solve the problem. How does docker know when there's changes in the code during build? I'm getting "Layer already exists" for each layer when I push the container to the repo (even if I `docker build --no-cache -t webhook .`) How does docker find the ip on which to host my app? It's been on localhost. Running apps in VMs, I've used `hostname -I` as my hostname for public deployment.

Comment: You can follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image) to create the web app with a custom image. The docker image shares the same layer and you can get more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured out my problems and mistakes with configuring ports, port forwarding, hostnames, and env vars between my node app, docker container, and azure web app config.

I didn't realize the tag for each docker build needs to be same name as the remote docker repository.

Thanks to the example from the article from the comments above, it made me realize my app within my docker container should be accessible on localhost within the same shell env for local testing. that is, `docker build -t jtara1/wh .` `id=$(docker run -p 80:3000 jtara1/wh)` `curl localhost` should output something like "Hello World" or whatever is returned in the response from your app from the root index for testing. Before, I was `docker exec -it $id sh` (effectively remotely accessing my local container) then getting a response from the app within there which caused confusions for me later on. Finally, `docker push jtara1/wh`

I noticed in the docker logs that azure uses docker to run my container using some port forwarding such as `docker run -p 53600:80 jtara1/wh` which indicates the docker container is accessible on port 53600 and forwards that traffic to port 80 (presumably my node app). But, I needed to define the env var, PORT, to be the port my node app uses which defaults to PORT=80; (In the article linked above, it suggests WEBSITES_PORT is the env var that azure web apps uses to determine which port my app is hosted on).

Traditionally, on a linux vm, I host on `$ hostname -I` and access it publicly on the vm's public ip. In my app, I'm hosting on 0.0.0.0 instead of the usual localhost so it is accessible by docker

I struggled with effectively managing my sensitive env vars (sometime ago and not in this issue) that the app needed while still trying to avoid having to manage, refactor, or update them in more than one place. I ended up just manually entering them in the application settings of the web app as there's fewer than 18 right now.

I did end up switching to just using the dockerfile without the docker-compose.yml as it was suffice for this deployment.

```
FROM node:8-alpine

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

ADD package.json /app/

RUN npm install

ADD . /app/

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["node", "server.js", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar problem with a Java-based Docker app.

Turned out that on Azure there is by default a timeout of 230 seconds for deployment of Docker containers, but can easily override this in the application settings using the key  `WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT`. Just set it to some higher value, i.e. `600` (= 10 minutes). Please note that the maximum value is 1800 seconds.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq